# Why does this yield AttrigbuteError when trying to update?

Tags: django-models

I'm trying to update a specific field value in a model database.

I think I've tried everything....I'm so frustrated...

Model:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    GRADELEVEL=[('P', 'Pre-K'), ('K', 'Kindergarten'), ('1', '1'), ('2', '2'), ('3', '3'), ('4', '4'), ('5', '5'),('6', '6'),('7', '7'), ('8', '8'), ('9', '9'), ('10', '10'), ('11', '11'), ('12', '12')]
    epicenterid = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=6)
    studentlname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    studentfname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    parentemail = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    parentphone = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    studentemail = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    studentphone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    studentgrade = models.CharField(max_length=120, choices=GRADELEVEL)
    readingperformancelevel = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=GRADELEVEL)
    mathperformancelevel = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=GRADELEVEL)
    studentbirthday = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    regularteacheremail = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    regularteacherlname =models.CharField(max_length=10)
    regularteacherfname =models.CharField(max_length=10)
    studentcreatedate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

View:

```
def edit_student_view(request):

    form = EditStudentForm(request.GET or None)
    q=Student.objects.all()
    epicenterid=q.epicenterid()
    if form.is_valid():
        epicenteridtoupdate = (EditStudentForm.GET.get())
        q=Student.objects.all()
        epicenterid=q.epicenterid()
        search = Student.filter(epicenterid=epicenteridtoupdate)
        search.update(studentfname='New First Name')
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'enrollment/editthisstudent.html', context)
```

I can update a specific record by putting the id number into the update command, but it absolutely will not search for and find the passed `epicenteridtoupdate` variable from the user input.

Please help....

Comment: Please do *not* use global variables. The above will not work since you each time set it to `None`, but using a global variable is a bad idea anyway. It would mean that for example if two users use the system simulteanously, they can set the variable, and thus the other user now gets records searched by the former.

Comment: A webserver should (nearly) always be implemented *stateless*.

Comment: It is also quite likely that the `epicenterid` should be a `ForeignKey` (to the user?)

Comment: Thank you for your comments Willem Van Onsem, but none of them are helping with making the search work.  The user has to initially input the epicenterid when they register a student, so it can't be foreign.